# Buying an e-book for a friend in Canada

Tags: epub, ebook-management, canada

I have tried to buy an e-book for a friend from Amazon, Barnes and Noble, and two other sites that don't come to mind right now. I have failed using all four accounts (even after contacting their respected CS). I live in Canada; so does he.

Is there a site I can use to send him the book? He has an iPhone and is willing to download an app to be able to receive the book and read it. (Note that I don't own any iOS products)

Any suggestions or sites or apps?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is currently a low-quality post; please edit your question to explain what has failed and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon.ca can't gift ebooks to Canadians but Amazon.com can.

Comment: This is quite a sparse answer - could you explain why and how amazon knows?

Comment: It's not sparse, it's simple. On Amazon.com, there's a "give as a gift" button, on Amazon.ca, there isn't. Though I wouldn't guarantee that a gift sent to a Canadian from Amazon.com would be readable - they restrict access by geolocation.

Answer (score 2):

In iTunes, there is an option to "Gift this book".

With the Mac version of iTunes, the "Buy Book" button that is directly below the cover art for the book in the upper left side of the page has a popup menu accessed by clicking on the down arrow on the far right of the button. "Gift this book" is the first option on that menu.

You would need an iTunes account to pay for the book, and your friend would probably need one to receive the book. He would then be able to access the book using Apple's *iBook* app.